# Networking in c# with a single computer

Tags: c#, .net, networking

I am trying to make a program that connects to another computer to be able to trransfer files directly in c#, nothing fancy.

Since I kinda of am a begginer (started to learn how to code in the beggining of the year) and never tried to do networking with c#. I began by reading about TCP in msdn. But, when testing i got  into a problem that I had overlooked. How am I going to do networking in a single computer?

when trying to connect to the server. I get a Exception saying that the device refused the connection.

how should I proceed?

I understand the problem, since I am essentialy trying to be the sender and receiver in the same IP and port. But still dont know how to solve it. Running a "Client app" and "Server app" still doenst work. if you know about networking, please help

Comment: "_I am essentialy trying to be the sender and receiver in the same IP and port._" No, that is not how it works. A receiver will listen on a well-known TCP port, while an application initiating a connection will use TCP port 0, and the OS will assign a random ephemeral port number. Ephemeral port numbers are in the 49152 to 65535 range, although the ephemeral ranges used by various OSes may differ slightly. .

Answer (score 1):

Your two programs normally wouldn't both use a TCP listener.  One would would be the "server" and listen on a TCP/IP port, and the other would be the "client" and connect to it.

But TCP/IP is not enough.  You need a "framing protocol" on top of TCP/IP to exchange messages or files.  You shouldn't "roll you own" here. Instead use an existing one.  HTTP is the obvious choice, as you can write an HTTP server in C# with like 2 lines of code.  See [Minimal API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis/overview?view=aspnetcore-7.0).

Comment: sorry, I wrote wrong my question. I did use a TCPListener and a client. thanks anyway, will check the link you send ;)